# Ruby: Why is CLOCK_MONOTONIC_PRECISE missing?

Tags: ruby

I'm using MRI Ruby 2.3.6, compiled for Cygwin.

The expression

```
Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC_PRECISE
```

raises the exception

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC_PRECISE
Did you mean?  Process::CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
```

Why? According to [the Ruby core docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Process.html), this constant should be available.

Comment: Does cygwin support `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`?

Comment: The functionality is probably not available on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Just found out the reason. The Documentation I looked up (which was the "most accurate" one for my Ruby version) does not mention an important aspect, which was added [in a later documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime). Actually, the availability of these constants depends on the platform for which this Ruby was compiled.

Comment: _"The documentation I looked up [...] does not mention an important aspect"_ – which documentation and aspect are you referring to?

Comment: This was always documented for `Process.clock_gettime` since the time the feature was first introduced [in Ruby 2.1.0](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime)

Comment: @Stefan : The documentation which I linked to in my original post. Have a look! It shows only the names of the constants, but no restriction on its usage. But if you look at the same page in the Ruby 2.5.0 docs, there is a link below each constant, and if we click on this link, we land on a page which states these limitations.

Answer (score 0):

if you have kind of '`rack-mini-profiler`' or having this so

remove this gem `gem 'rack-mini-profiler`' from gem file

and before remove,
clear `Gemfile.lock`  and
run `bundle`
hope that working